# Cannot query field "me" on type "Query".GraphQL: Validation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-tag

Getting this error when trying to use my query. Everything is fine in graphql playground just running into this issue with my app. I;m new to graphql (if it wasnt obvious already) so let me know if there's anything else I need to show.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing graphql-tag to no luck.

Here is where my error currently is

```
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const CURRENT_USER_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    me {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`;

const User = props => (
  <Query {...props} query={CURRENT_USER_QUERY}>
    {payload => props.children(payload)}
  </Query>
);

export default User;
```

my schema

```
type Query {
  users(query: String): [User!]!
  me: User
}
```

my resolver

```
const Query = {
  me(parents, args, { request, prisma }, info) {
    if (!request.userId) {
      return null;
    }
    return prisma.query.users(
      {
        where: { id: request.userId }
      },
      info
    );
  }

export { Query as default };
```

Should be getting back an individual user.

Comment: Are you sure your client is configured to connect to your server and not another one?

Comment: Yep all is good there.

Comment: That error is coming from the server you're querying, so either it's not the same query, it's not the same server or you've updated the server server since running the query in playground.